# Multiple Delete operation is not working

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am trying to delete the data by checking multiple checkboxes, but when I choose the checkboxes from the screen and hit the delete button then the only top row gets deleted. Means no matter which row I select it deletes the only first entry of the table. Please help me.

Delete.servlet

```
delPage = request.getParameter("delPage");
    patientId = request.getParameter("pid");
    if(delPage.equals("true")) {

        int p = Integer.parseInt(patientId);  
        patientDao = new PatientDAO();
        boolean b = patientDao.isPatientDeleted(p);
        if (b) {
            System.out.println("Patient Deleted Successfully .... !");
            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/Pages/MasterPage.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
        }else
            System.out.println("Patient deleting failed ... ! ");
    }

    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/Pages/MasterPage.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);
            }
```

Masterpage.jsp

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addNewPatient(){
debugger;
var addNewPat = "true";
document.form.method = "POST";
document.form.action = "addPatient?newPage="+addNewPat;
document.form.submit();
}
function deletePatient(){
    debugger;
    var pid = document.getElementById("del").value;
    var delpatient = "true";
    document.form.method = "POST";
    document.form.action = "deletePatient?delPage="+ delpatient+"&pid="+pid;
    document.form.submit();
}
</script>      
    <c:forEach var="user" items="${patients}">
      <tr>
       <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="del" value="<c:out value="${user.patientId}"> 
    </c:out>" >  
       </td>
    <td>
      <input type="hidden" id="delpatient"><c:out value="${user.patientId}"> 
       </c:out>
                <td><c:out value="${user.patientName}" /></td>
                 <td><c:out value="${user.patientAddress}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${user.patientPhone}" /></td>

            </tr>

        </c:forEach>

<div class="ui small button"  onClick="deletePatient(<c:out value="${user.patientId}"></c:out>)">
    <i class="trash ulternate icon"></i>
Delete
</div>
```

DeletePatientServlet.java

```
public class DeletePatientServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private PatientBean patient = null;
private PatientDAO patientDao = null;
String delPage = null ;
String patientId = null;

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException {
    int patientId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("pid"));
       PatientDAO patientDao = new PatientDAO();
     patientDao.isPatientDeleted(patientId);   
            System.out.println("Patient Deleted Successfully .... !");
            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/Pages/MasterPage.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);

}
}
```

Comment: `${user}` is left in page scope _after_ your c:forEach loop ends, so the last patient is deleted when you click the button. Give each row a button and your problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so there are a bunch of mistakes in your code. I'll start with the jsp...

You are trying to pass parameters via the servlet url with a `POST` request

```
document.form.method = "POST";
document.form.action = "deletePatient?delPage="+ delpatient+"&pid="+pid;
```

You cannot pass data in the url with post requests. You need to change your servlet to a `GET` if you want to do this.

Also, in this line:

```
<div class="ui small button"  onClick="deletePatient(<c:out value="${user.patientId}"></c:out>)">
```

you are passing a value to your deletePatient method. But your deletePatient method does not have an option to pass a value:

```
function deletePatient(){ // no value being passed here?
    debugger;
    var pid = document.getElementById("del").value;
    var delpatient = "true";
    document.form.method = "POST";
    document.form.action = "deletePatient?delPage="+ delpatient+"&pid="+pid;
    document.form.submit();
}
```

You can also just do:

```
${user.patientId}
```

instead of:

```
<c:out value="${user.patientId}"></c:out>
```

Another problem with your code is this, you cannot have multiple elements in your HTML with the same id. This is illegal HTML, and it's the reason why you are getting the same id each time:

```
 <c:forEach var="user" items="${patients}">
      <tr>
       <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="del" value="<c:out value="${user.patientId}">  //no this is bad.
    </c:out>" >  
       </td>
    <td>
      <input type="hidden" id="delpatient"><c:out value="${user.patientId}"> 
       </c:out>
                <td><c:out value="${user.patientName}" /></td>
                 <td><c:out value="${user.patientAddress}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${user.patientPhone}" /></td>

            </tr>

        </c:forEach>
```

Your delete button is not even inside your loop, so it will not work:

```
<div class="ui small button"  onClick="deletePatient(<c:out value="${user.patientId}"></c:out>)"> //this will pass the same id each time
    <i class="trash ulternate icon"></i>
Delete
</div>
```

Try something like this instead (for delete only):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function deletePatient(e){
    var patientid = e.getAttribute("data-patientid");
    deletePatientForm(patientid);
}
function deletePatientForm(pid) {
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    var input = document.createElement("input"); 

    form.method = "POST";
    form.action = "deletePatient";   

    input.value=pid;
    input.name="pid";
    form.appendChild(input);  

    document.body.appendChild(form);

    form.submit();
}
</script>  

<c:forEach var="user" items="${patients}">
   <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>address</th>
    <th>phone</th>
    <th></th>
   <tr>

   <tr>
    <td>${user.patientId}</td>
    <td>${user.patientName}</td>
    <td>${user.patientAddress}</td>
    <td>${user.patientPhone}</td>
    <td>
     <div class="ui small button" onClick="deletePatient(this)" data-patientid="${user.patientId}"><i class="trash ulternate icon"></i> Delete</div>
    </td>
   <tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Then in the post of your servlet:

```
int patientId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("pid"));

   PatientDAO patientDao = new PatientDAO();
   patientDao.isPatientDeleted(patientId);   

RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/Pages/MasterPage.jsp");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

If you have any problems or questions let me know.

Comment: ur code giving this error `HTTP Status 500 - For input string: "[object HTMLDivElement]"
type Exception report
message For input string: "[object HTMLDivElement]"
description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
exception java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: [object HTMLDivElement]` And also I want to delete records by using checkboxes. Your code creates a button for each individual record.

Comment: What area of the code does that error pertain to exactly? And yeah i got rid of your checkboxes, but you could easily replace the buttons to checkboxes that have listeners to submit on change

Comment: I have updated my code. It showing error at line `int patientId=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("pid"));
` In DeletePatientServlet.java file

Comment: You're getting a null pointer because the parameter pid is not being sent. And you can't parseInt on null. Check your code matches what i wrote exactly. Make sure ${user.patientId} is actually outputting something.

Comment: Check the form headers to see if the value is being sent